# How to get the $? from a command run via ssh

Tags: ssh, ksh

I have a script that will use ssh to run a command on a remote node.  The remote node is an appliance so I can't (encouraged not to) make changes on it.  Right now I have a script like this:

```
  ssh REMOTE-NODE -l login "ls" > output 2>&1

  status=$?
```

So `$status` will have the status of the ssh command.  How can I get the `$?` status of the remote command (ls in this example, but for any command called)?  I'm unable to create an intermediary script on the remote node that could return the status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't `ssh` return it as usual?

> EXIT STATUS
>       ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

```
$ ssh user@localhost 'exit 123' ; echo $?
user@localhost's password: 
123
```

Though as @thrig hints in the comments, if the ssh client is killed due to a signal, `$?` may show the usual 128+signal number instead of 255, even though it's not the exit code of the remote command. Instead, on a quick test, it seems that if the remote command exits due to signal, `ssh` returns 255.

Comment: I didn't realize that ssh would return the status of the remote command called.  I assumed it would return the status of the ssh command alone.   So, the 255 status indicates ssh failed, and any other value is the status of the command passed?  Thanks.

Comment: 255 does not solely indicate that `ssh` failed, as a quick test of `kill -9` on a `ssh host 'sleep 9999'` should show

Comment: @Scavenger, hmm, mostly so. It returns 255 if it can't connect etc, but it seems to also return 255 in some cases if the remote command dies due to a signal. And it doesn't return 255 if the ssh client is killed by a signal. Annoying little exceptions...